# Unable to select/pass the selected URI of Gallery video in the android 12 and 13 and not able to view in the selected screen

Tags: android, kotlin, video, mp4, video-editing

I am using the android app and trying to add the gallery videos to my video editing screen. But it failed to show the video and showing a black screen.

Can any one let me know what I am doing wrong.

I am click on the gallery icon and try to open the video from the ACTION_PICK and send that video to the next Activity.

**Problem:** I am getting this **error** in LogCat:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: 
UID 10170 does not have permission to content:

//com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F25/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1574077794 

[user 0] at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull
```

Here is my code:

**VideoFragment.kt**

```
R.id.imageViewVideo -> {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 32) {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null) // It shows the videos alone
                intent.type = "video/*"
                resultLauncher.launch(intent)
            } else {
            requestPermission()
            }
        }

private val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent? = result.data
            val videoUri: Uri = data?.data!!
            Log.i("videoUri", videoUri.toString()) // content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000000024/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1940625115
            val videoPath = parsePath(videoUri)
            if (videoPath != null) {
                Log.i("videoPath", videoPath) 
 /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_20231115_163657.mp4
                Log.i("videoPath22", videoUri.path.toString()) /-1/2/content://media/external/video/media/1000000024/ORIGINAL/NONE/video/mp4/1940625115
            }
           

            val intent = Intent(this@Camera2VideoFragment.requireContext(), SelectVideoActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("path", videoPath)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent)
}
}
```

Next Activity File: (SelectVideoActivity.kt)

onCreate()

```
val source = File(intent!!.getStringExtra("path")!!)
                    copyFile(source, inputFile)
                    Log.i("input file ===", inputFile.toString())


@Throws(IOException::class)
    fun copyFile(sourceFile: File?, destFile: File) {
        try {
                if (!destFile.parentFile!!.exists()) destFile.parentFile!!.mkdirs()
                if (!destFile.exists()) {
                    destFile.createNewFile()
                }
                var source: FileChannel? = null
                var destination: FileChannel? = null

                source = FileInputStream(sourceFile).channel
                destination = FileOutputStream(destFile).channel
                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size())
            }
            catch (e:Exception){
                Log.i("error","selectvideo ${e.message}")
            }finally {
//                source?.close()
//                destination?.close()
                initViews()
                setListener()
            }
    }
```

**For the lowest version of Androids the path looks like below and it works fine**

Filepath:

/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20231121_193407.mp4 /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.app.packagename/files/app-name/1700718359149.mp4

Code:

```
private lateinit var inputFile: File
```

onCreate method:

```
     inputFile =
                File(getExternalFilesDir("slow-mow")!!.absolutePath.plus("/" + "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4"))
```

Comment: Unable to select? I think you can.

Comment: Do not pass uri.path but uri.string. and you need to take persistable uri permission for which you need to use ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.t

Comment: I can select, but the uri passing is failed

Comment: @blackapps Thanks. Any sample for this?

Comment: @blackapps uri.string is not available. It has uri.toString()

Comment: Well you should get here a string that starts with content://.

Comment: Yes I get a content://.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255996/discussion-between-sejn-and-blackapps).

Comment: It also shows a black screen.

Comment: You mean that SelectVideoActivity shows a black screen? Then what goes wrong there? For a test just first open an InputStream there for the uri and read some bytes from it. But that activity did not select the file so why Select.... as name?

Comment: I am not sure the SelectVideoActivity is black screen. Just a navigation goes black screen

Comment: I have enabled debugger on the SelectVideoActivity onCreate. The black screen not stopped anywhere.

Comment: @blackapps I am getting bytes from the uri

Comment: Where? In the SelectVideoActivity?

Comment: No in the same Videofragment file

Comment: Now getting this crash for me java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10170 does not have permission to content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F25/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1574077794 [user 0]
                                                                                                     at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull

Comment: Post logcat lines readable in your post. Not in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```kotlin
                val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), SelectVideoActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("path", videoUri.path)
                startActivity(intent)
```

with:

```kotlin
                val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), SelectVideoActivity::class.java)
                intent.setData(videoUri).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                startActivity(intent)
```

And, in `SelectVideoActivity`, use `getData()` on the `Intent` to retrieve the `Uri`.

See [this blog post of mine](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Even better would be to only have one activity and use fragments or composables for separate screens.

Comment: It failed to navigate to the screen

Comment: @sejn: I am sorry, but I do not know what exactly you mean by that. Can you please explain in greater detail what you are seeing? For example, are you crashing? If so, use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: I am seeing a black screen

Comment: app_time_stats: avg=9.11ms min=1.93ms max=146.44ms count=48
 TrafficStats                        D  tagSocket(75) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
Compatibil...geReporter                      D  Compat change id reported: 78294732; UID 10164; state: ENABLED

Comment: @sejn: "I am seeing a black screen" -- perhaps there is a bug in `SelectVideoActivity`. You might try getting commenting out most of its logic. Also, please note that a `Uri` returned by `ACTION_PICK` (or anything else) does not have to point to a file on a filesystem that you can read.

Comment: "You might try getting commenting out most of its logic" -- Is Anything specific to this in SelectActivity getting the Intent file path? 
FYI, I have used the  UwMediaPicker to pick the videos works upto v30. While moving to 31 to 33 it not working. `UwMediaPicker.with(this).setGalleryMode(UwMediaPicker.GalleryMode.VideoGallery) .setGridColumnCount(4).setMaxSelectableMediaCount(1).setLightStatusBar(true)
.launch { selectedMediaList ->val intent = Intent(requireActivity(),SelectVideoActivity::class.java) intent.putExtra("path", selectedMediaList!![0].mediaPath) startActivity(intent)}  }`

Comment: @sejn: "Is Anything specific to this in SelectActivity getting the Intent file path?" -- **there is no file path**. Use the `Uri` itself, such as with `ContentResolver`, `DocumentFile`, or your favorite image-loader library or video player library (e.g., ExoPlayer). Then, either follow the instructions in my answer to pass the `Uri` to another activity or only have one activity (using fragments or composables to represent separate screens).

Comment: I have used the  ContentResolver like the below. `val videoPath = parsePath(videoUri)` Here is the method for the parsePath `private fun parsePath(uri: Uri?): String? {
  val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        val cursor: Cursor? = requireActivity().contentResolver.query(uri!!, projection, null, null, null) return if (cursor != null) { val columnIndex: Int = cursor .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA) cursor.moveToFirst()val path = cursor.getString(columnIndex) cursor.close()
 path } else null }`i get the path /storage/emulated/0/Movies/VID_2121_197.mp4

Comment: @sejn: Sorry, by "use `ContentResolver`" I meant "use `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`". There is no requirement that your `Uri` resolves to anything using that code, and there is no requirement for you to have filesystem access to any path that you get back from `parsePath()`.

Comment: If I use the `val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver             inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`, still facing the same. I have passed the inputStream like this `val byteArray = inputStream.readBytes() intent.putExtra("videoByteArray", byteArray) startActivity(intent)`. And get this in the SelectVideoActivity and  `val videoByteArray: ByteArray? = intent?.getByteArrayExtra("videoByteArray") val tempFile = createTempFile("tempVideo", ".mp4", cacheDir)`.The inputStream needs to pass as bytes, so I retrieved the byte to tempfile. Failed

Comment: @sejn: *Pass* the `Uri` as I outline in the answer. *Use* the `Uri` *inside of* `SelectVideoActivity`. Or, again, have just a single activity rather than two, using fragments or composables to represent separate screens.

Comment: So need to read the bytes in SelectVideoActivity to uri, not need  to use the path correct

Comment: @sejn: Correct. The path is useless, even if you can get it, and you might not be able to do so.

Comment: Can you let me know why the startActivity(intent) not opening the activity as expected.

Comment: @sejn: As [I wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77514967/unable-to-select-pass-the-selected-uri-of-gallery-video-in-the-android-12-and-13/77515682?noredirect=1#comment136693572_77515682), it may be opening the activity, but there may be bugs in the activity. Perhaps you could start a simple "hello, world" activity. Or perhaps you could use breakpoints or custom logging statements to see whether your activity is being started and is misbehaving.

Comment: I have added the breakpoints on the SelectVideoActivity onCreate. But while showing the black screen it not comes in to this activity. Also I have tried creating a new activity file and added the filename for the navigation. Still it not redirecting to thenewly created screen

Comment: If I pass the startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)). It goes to a white screen but the oncreate breakpoints not entered into the activity file

Comment: I am getting the message as    Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 2532368 bytes

Comment: @sejn: You may be putting too much into the `Intent`. The `Uri` is going to be much smaller than that. This error can also come from `onSaveInstanceState()` and things based upon it, such as `rememberSavable()` in Compose UI.

Comment: I have send the same uri straighty to next activity file. Still the navigation to that screen failed for me. Is this is a good approach? `content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/2/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fvideo%2Fmedia%2F1000000023/ORIGINAL/NONE/video%2Fmp4/1956790097`

If I convert to byte and send it to activity it shows the file is largeSize. uri passing not working as expected. 
It starting the activity for lowest versions and failed to start for hightest version alone.`override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256050/discussion-between-sejn-and-commonsware).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with action pick video, it works fine and retured data.
You dont need `path` of source video, that cause the security problem, just use `uri` and read it with `ContentResolver`.

```kotlin
// copy file
val uri = intent.getData()
contentResolver.openFileInputStream(uri)?.use { inStream ->
  val destFile = // you dest file, prefer to use context.getExternalFilesDir
  destFile.outputStream().use { os ->
    inStream.copyTo(os)
  }
}
```

Noted

- Android 12 devices new installation targetting sdk 30: requestLegacyExternalStorage is always false. So you need handle for storage permission.
- I prefer use app dir (`Android/data/package-name/...`) to copy file, save edited fil, then you can scan the file to Gallery if you need.

Answer (score 0):

It got worked with the below ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and saved the file in cache and used the path

```
R.id.imageViewVideo -> {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, null)
                    intent.type = "video/*"
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                                data?.data?.also { uri ->
                                    //Permission needed if you want to retain access even after reboot
                                    requireContext().contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            
                                    val path = copyInCacheDir(uri)
                                    Log.e("file path", "onActivityResult: path ${path.toString()} ")
                                    val intent = Intent(requireActivity(), com.example.exoplayerslowmotion.SelectVideoActivity::class.java)
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                                    intent.putExtra("path", path.toString())
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                    requireActivity().finish()
                                }
                            }}
            
            private fun copyInCacheDir(videoUri: Uri): String? {
                    try {
                        val contentResolver = requireContext().contentResolver
                       
                        if (videoUri.authority == "com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider") {
                            contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                                videoUri,
                                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                            )
                        }
                        val returnCursor = contentResolver.query(videoUri, null, null, null, null)
                        returnCursor?.use { cursor ->
                            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                val displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
                                val sizeIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE)
            
                                val displayName = cursor.getString(displayNameIndex)
                                val size = cursor.getLong(sizeIndex)
            
                                val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(videoUri)
                                val cacheDir = requireContext().cacheDir
                                val outputFile = File(cacheDir, displayName)
                                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)
            
                                val bufferSize = 1024
                                val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                                var bytesRead: Int
            
                                while (inputStream?.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize).also { bytesRead = it!! } != -1) {
                                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                                }
            
                                inputStream?.close()
                                outputStream.close()
            
                                Log.d("Video Copy", "Video copied to: ${outputFile.absolutePath}")
                                return outputFile.absolutePath
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        Log.e("Video Copy Error", "Error copying video: ${ex.message}", ex)
                    }
            
                    return null
                }
```